# Multiple Vue apps with routing in the same page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to reproduce the following behaviour:

[image: project]

VueJS App 1 & VueJS App2 are whole VueJS applications with routing and store.

I would like to be able to deploy them as standalone (available on routes /my-route1 and /my-route2) and also as instances in another page (/my-route3).

The idea is that I can create as many instances of my Vue apps as I want. The routing and stores should be independent between the apps.

I have already been able to make it work through iframes but I would like to find a better way of doing it.

The current issue I am facing is that all those instances are sharing the same root Vue instance, would it be possible to create our own local Vue when instantiating them ? As I would like to be able to use global components, but they should only be global to the app their are created in.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: why do you need to create multiple vue app? why don't you create multiple components instead?

Comment: Those vue apps are already created. The application I am working for are not using single SPA so each url (/my-route1 & /my-route2) are its own Vue application at the moment. They use their own vue routing inside this. I haven't seen a way to use Vue routing inside a simple component.

Comment: *would it be possible to create our own local Vue when instantiating them* - yes, refactor apps to `Vue.extend()` instance instead of global `import Vue from 'vue'`, i.e. batch replace it with `import Vue from '@/vue'`.

Comment: @EstusFlask Usually `@` is defined in Webpack to make it work, I do not see how it would make it work for me in that case. Could you be more explicit please ?

Comment: That's right. In case Webpack was configured, `@/vue` is supposed to refer to `src/vue.js` module that contains `export default Vue.extend()`. Then all plugins that are applied to this Vue instance with `Vue.use` won't affect global `Vue`.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at this questing a few times now over the last few days and concluded this is a bad concept, I can only make the following suggesting and only because nobody else has answered so far, so here is a possible alternative to consider...

Assuming you have access to the separate apps source and are indeed in control of them I would convert them into components which I think could be less problematic given you are going to have all sorts of issues with cache versioning (file name hashing) and code splitting in regards to getting all the assets required to load correctly, it will be a nightmare.

The separate apps really should have been created as comprehensive [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) with their source code each in their own sub-directory.

By utilizing dynamic imports with code splitting your complicated apps parts would be auto-loaded be loaded as when needed.

As components the tiles could have been easily output as desired by making use of an iterator to output desired tile content using `<component :is="myView"/>`.

```js
// Register app components:

const Dynamics = {

  // A component to use while the async component is loading
  loading: LoadingComponent,

  // A component to use if the load fails
  error: ErrorComponent,

  // Delay before showing the loading component. Default: 200ms.
  delay: 200,

  // The error component will be displayed if a timeout is
  // provided and exceeded. Default: Infinity.
  timeout: 3000

}

Vue.component('application-one', () => ({ ...Dynamics, component: import('@/components/applications/app-one/app.vue') }))

Vue.component('application-two', () => ({ ...Dynamics, component: import('@/components/applications/app-two/app.vue') }))
```

```js
// Dashboard.vue

<template>

 <div id="dashboard">

   <template v-for="(app, index) of applications">

     <component :is="app.name" :key="index" v-bind="app" />

   </template>

 </div>

</template>

<script>

  export default {

    name: 'dashboard',

    // example only, real list would be generated from an API endpoint call?
    data: () => ({
      
      applications: [
        { name: 'application-one', width: '33%', height: '100%' },
        { name: 'application-two', width: '33%', height: '100%' },
        { name: 'application-one', width: '33%', height: '33%' },
        { name: 'application-one', width: '33%', height: '33%' },
        { name: 'application-two', width: '33%', height: '33%' },
      ]

    })
 
  }

</script>
```

> Hope this gives you the basis for some alternative approaches.